# ros install process freezes at "Detected ros_comm" on mac os x

Tags: rosinstall, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I get this message upon installation and then the process just freezes

```
  Bootstrapping ROS build
  Detected ros_comm bootstrapping it too.
```

please help me

Thanks, farid

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10733/ros-install-process-freezes-at-%22detected-ros_comm%22-on-mac-os-x/) by [farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/898/farid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-27**:
@farid, you can edit your original post to include this information.

**Comment by [farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/898/farid/) on 2011-07-26**:
?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop&overlay=no

**Comment by [farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/898/farid/) on 2011-07-26**:
rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=diamondback&variant=desktop&overlay=no"^[[Arosinstall operating on /Users/Infiniteskills/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  /Users/Infiniteskills/ros/.rosinstall, http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py

**Comment by [farid](https://answers.ros.org/users/898/farid/) on 2011-07-26**:
I did the Desktop full install using the code in the next 2 comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-07-26**:
Can you provide more context? Also, is  "bootstrapping it too" actually part of the error message? If not, please copy and paste the exact error message (do not retype it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0